# Digital Ocean Droplet running Docker -> Jenkins -> Docker -> Jest is shutting down

Tags: docker, node.js, digital-ocean

I have a droplet running docker that runs jenkins.

I have a jenkins pipeline that runs docker and a `node` test with jest.

It seems like when it gets to the test stage it collapses the whole server.

The server shuts down and i have to run `docker-compose up` to get jenkins back up.

How can I fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Convert docker-compose to v2 and add a `mem_limit`.